# Strong union of two lists

Tags: sml

I've defined functions:

```
fun concaten(x,y) =
    if (x = [])
      then y
      else hd(x) :: concaten(tl(x),y);
```

as well as:

```
fun existsin(x,L) =
  if (L=[])
  then false
  else if (x = hd(L))
         then true
         else existsin(x,tl(L));
```

and am now trying to define a function of type `(((list * list) -> list) -> list)` that looks vaguely like the following:

```
fun strongunion(x,y) =
  val xy = concaten(x,y);
  if xy=[]
    then []
  if (existsin(hd(xy),tl(xy)) andalso x!= [])
    then strongunion(tl(x),y)
    else if (existsin(hd(xy),tl(xy)) andalso x = [])
           then strongunion(x,tl(y))
           else if (x != [])
                  then hd(xy) :: strongunion(tl(x),y)
                  else hd(xy) :: strongunion(x,tl(y));
```

which takes the "strong" union of two lists, i.e. it combats faulty inputs (lists with element duplicates). This code is, of course, syntactically invalid, but the reason I included it was to show what such a function would look like in an imperative language.

The way I started going about doing this was to first concatenate the lists, then remove duplicated elements from that concatenation (well, technically I am adding non-duplicates to an empty list, but these two operations are consequentially equivalent). To do this, I figured I would design the function to take two lists (type list*list), transform them into their concatenation (type list), then do the duplicate removal (type list), which would be of type `(((list*list) -> list) -> list)`.

My issue is that I have no idea how to do this in SML. I'm required to use SML for a class for which I'm a TA, otherwise I wouldn't bother with it, and instead use something like Haskell. If someone can show me how to construct such higher-order functions, I should be able to take care of the rest, but I just haven't come across such constructions in my reading of SML literature.

Comment: It would be almost identical in Haskell, except for minor differences in punctuation.

Comment: In Haskell it might look like [`Data.List.union`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#union); except that version doesn't assume that its inputs have no duplicates and runs in *O(n²)* to remove any. Haskell has [`Data.Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Set.html) for efficient sets where SML/NJ has [`RedBlackSetFn`](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2003sp/sml-nj-library.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unsure if *strong union* means anything other than just *union*. If you assume that a function `union : ''a list * ''a list -> ''a list` takes two lists of elements without duplicates as inputs, then you can make it produce the unions without duplicates by conditionally inserting each element from the one list into the other:

```
(* insert a single element into a list *)
fun insert (x, []) = [x]
  | insert (x, xs as (y::ys)) =
    if x = y
      then xs
      else y::insert(x, ys)

(* using manual recursion *)
fun union ([], ys) = ys
  | union (x::xs, ys) = union (xs, insert (x, ys))

(* using higher-order list-combinator *)
fun union (xs, ys) = foldl insert ys xs
```

Trying this:

```
- val demo = union ([1,2,3,4], [3,4,5,6]);
> val demo = [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2] : int list
```

Note, however, that `union` wouldn't be a higher-order function, since it doesn't take functions as input or return functions. You could use a slightly stretched definition and make it curried, i.e. `union : ''a list -> ''a list -> ''a list`, and say that it's higher-order when partially applying it to only one list, e.g. like `union [1,2,3]`. It wouldn't even be fully polymorphic since it accepts only lists of types that can be compared (e.g. you can't take the union of two sets of functions).